# take a cell content from an external html through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need some help...I have this webpage (`http://93.62.201.235/maree/ESPORTAZIONI/MESE/Stazione_PuntaSalute_CanalGrande.html`) which creates a table with high tide values in Venice.
I need a specific value (the third cell on the last raw) and get it in a variable...

I tried with this jQuery code only to see if it works with a table I created in an external html page:

```
function myFunction()
{

$("#result").load("tableappend.html table", function(){
var y = document.getElementById("myTable2").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
console.log(y);
});

}
```

This is the code of the "external" page:

```
<html>

<body>

<table id="myTable2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

</body>
</html>
```

It should write "cell 1" on the console.log but it doesn't work...
Any solution?

Comment: "it doesn't work" What does mean? Any error in console?

Comment: no errors, it doesn't show anything...

Comment: Inside load callback, just test: `alert($('#myTable2').length);` Result?  BTW, you could check data returned from load() method, is it expected result?

Comment: nothing displayed (no alert)

Comment: @user3161604 so load callback is not called. I guess when you call `myFunction()` element `$("#result")` doesn't exist

Comment: ok,sorry...my fault (I'm still on the holiday mood...). now,how can I get a specific cell in a specific raw from the webpage I posted on the top? 'cause it doesn't have an ID, I tried with "getElementsByTagName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any cross domain request you need to consider about [CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

You can achieve this using JSONP for JSON calls

Or send an `Origin` header as part of your request. If both the parties are agreed to share between, you can make it success

UPDATE:

Since your question is not explains what type of error, we assume and giving some answer

main.html

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

tableappend.html

```
<html>

<body>

<table id="myTable2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

</body>
</html>
```

In main.html

```
function myFunction()
{
   //load the tableappend.html page, in the same site under same root

   $("#result").load("tableappend.html table", 
           function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
           alert(textStatus) // should be success


   }
}
```

Comment: But OP should have an error in console if it was a cross domain error.

Comment: Ya, true, boring that we have to ask for that... My car is broken, what to do? Damn...

Comment: @A.Wolff, I thought it may be CORS issue, since he is loading from external domain and `Origin` is not set. So I thought sharing the info about CORS may be useful here.